# How To Update User Profile to user authentication from scratch

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have followed the revised Railscast for user authentication from scratch.

I wanted to know how I can add in parts for user to modify profile as I have other fields that they need to enter after registering such as gender, ethnicity, career, about me, children, height, etc.

Is there a tutorial that shows you how to do this or can someone help point me in the right direction?

My project files can be viewed at https://github.com/pwz2k/date

**UPDATE**

I have started working on it, not sure if I am doing this right. I want the user to be able to modify their account settings (fields used when registering).

Below is my edit.html in the /users folder.

```
<h1>Account Information</h1>

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
      <ul>
        <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %><br/>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br/>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :username %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :username %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :zip_code %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :zip_code %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :birthday %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :birthday %>
    </div>  
    <div class="actions"><%= f.submit %></div>
<% end %>
```

Here's my routes:

```
Dating::Application.routes.draw do
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
  get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
  get 'edit' => 'edit#edit'

  resources :users
  resources :sessions
  resources :password_resets

  root to: 'users#new'
```

And here is what I added to users_controller that I am not sure I did properly:

```
  def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:user])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:user])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Account updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
  end
```

How I will eventually have everything working is user will go to /edit to modify their account settings with all their private information that was filled our during registration. Then users can edit the profile information (gender, race, career, about me, etc) directly on their profile page (will use in-place editing). So I just need to know if the steps I have taken are correct (I haven't used the terminal yet) and  if so how do I get the edit page to display as it shows routing error atm.

Comment: revised railscasts aren't publicly accessible, so show us some code. on that basis, we can suggest something

Comment: I have added github link to show all files. This should help https://github.com/pwz2k/date

Answer (score 2):

Just a few general pointers.

In the Railscasts the `users_controller`'s `new` and `create` actions are being created. You'd like to edit a user, so you could build out the `edit` and `update` actions of this very controller.

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ...
  def new
    # exists
  end

  def create
    # exists
  end

  def edit
    # load the current_user; make sure a user can only edit his record!
  end

  def update
    # save edit for the current_user, same security as above
  end
end
```

In your routes you could figure out how to route a `resource :profile` singular resource [(Rails guides)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) to map to the appropriate actions.

Comment: Thanks I have updated my post with what I have done so far. Not sure I'm going in the right direction though.